# How to integrate banner AIRPUSH in .java

Tags: java, airpush

I want to put a banner on my app, the normal and easy way is put it into the .xml file but i want to do it at one of my .java files.

this is what airpush said that i must to do it but i have this error.

```
/* AdView Class is same as View Class. You can use the Adview object as View object. */
AdView adView=new AdView(this, AdView.BANNER_TYPE_IN_APP_AD, AdView.PLACEMENT_TYPE_INTERSTITIAL, false, false, 
 AdView.ANIMATION_TYPE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
 adView.setAdListener(this);
```

i have error here adView.setAdListener(this);

Comment: you should declare your setAdListener http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Bundle_SDK_1.0_Documentation